# How do tag subscriptions work?

Tags: support, bug, tags, email

I know I can hover over a tag and click on subscribe. It then says I get an email. In the email it says I should confirm. When I click the link (`https://stackexchange.com/filters/email-confirm/<somenumber>`) in the email, I am sent to a web page on stackexchange.com with a "Page Not Found" message and a panda sign.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get sent to a stackexchange.com page where I am asked to login.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug/problem with Vivaldi browser which I'm using. Cross-site authentication through my launchpad OpenID handle does not work with it. With Firefox it works.